# Multidimensional C# Arrays Length Problem

Tags: c#, python, tensorflow, tensorflowsharp

I'm using a package called TensorFlowSharp, and it returns a value in C# that is interpreted as a variable of type `float[,,,,]`. But the dimensions of this variable are `(0,7,7,5,7)`.

Is this variable an empty array or can I access the elements I think are in the rest of the dimensions?

I have tried accessing `x[0,0,0,0,0]` but it says `Index out of range`. This has occurred because a neural network in Python was passed a numpy array to create a tensor of shape `(None, 7,7,5,7)` and is then translating a C# tensor class into a fundamental C# data type.

Answer (score 0):

To get a specific value, use `array[index, index]` for example.

You can find some information on multidimensional arrays here: [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/arrays/multidimensional-arrays)

Comment: Perhaps I should edit the question. When I write x[0,0,0,0,0] where x is the variable in question it says index out of range, but I expect some output.

Comment: Well, so you have basically nothing there I guess.

Comment: Perhaps I need to edit the original Python code to remove the None shapes or find a better way to translate the tensor into float[,,,,]....